# Can I get back my saved data?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have got really far in my second profile in Skyrim, level 41. It took a long time to get back to that level, because I had got a game-breaking bug on my last profile and I erased it by accident as well as my other messed up profile.

Is there anyway to get my saved data back on the Xbox 360? If there isn't, I will not play Skyrim again for a very long time and I have no other option. Please help.

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. So you deleted your saved data in Skyrim and want to get it back somehow? Is that what you want?

Comment: Ya sorry i will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible but not easy. It depends on how much data was actually erased and how much has been written since then.

Restoring deleted files on an Xbox is similar to restoring PC files. When files are deleted, they are often not actually deleted- the system just erases any reference to the file and may overwrite it when it needs to.

To get the data back, you would need to somehow connect your hard drive to a PC and access it, then run some disk rescue software on it. This might retrieve your save.

Comment: @jasonvalderrama If you do plan to do data recovery you should use your Xbox as little as possible, and certainly save as little as possible to the hard drive, until you are able to try to get the save file back. The more you use it in the mean time the greater the chance that the Xbox may decide to write new data over the file.

Comment: Why can't i play the xbox wouldn't it be ok if don't use the hard drive