# I started to play Skyrim, but all the save files are deleted

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So, I used to be around level 40 on Skyrim and I haven't played the game in ages but now i've started to play it again, and when I played it, it took me back to Level 18. I went onto 'LOAD GAME' and all my progress had been deleted. If there a way to recover them so I can get back to playing at level 40?

Comment: What playform are you on?

Comment: I play on Xbox 360

Comment: 1.) Make sure you're on the same account 2.) Load the same save 3.) (unlikely) You deleted it

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a different account, or even accidentaly delete all your save files? If the following is false, try to see if you can retirve the saves back, though you didn't deleted them. As mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161993/can-i-get-back-my-saved-data):

> It may be possible but not easy. It depends on how much data was actually erased and how much has been written since then.
>
> Restoring deleted files on an Xbox is similar to restoring PC files. When files are deleted, they are often not actually deleted- the system just erases any reference to the file and may overwrite it when it needs to.
>
> To get the data back, you would need to somehow connect your hard drive to a PC and access it, then run some disk rescue software on it. This might retrieve your save.